# Synthetic version of foot odor

Tags: smell

I'd like to produce a synthetic version of foot odor for joke purposes. My company sells novelties.  What could I use to create something virtually identical? Would simply mixing the correct proportions of 3-Methylbutanoic acid, Propionic acid, Butyric acid & Methanethiol do it?  Would I need Ammonia?  (I found [this](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0008951).)

I probably don't need all the other fatty acids.  Since Methanethiol is a gas, how would I integrate that?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Considering this doesn't look like something most chemists have tried, you'll probably have to experiment yourself. You might get some insight or predictions here, but to know for sure only if you try it (or find someone who did). That's how chemists usually figure out if something will work anyway.

Comment: This is one of the areas researched in WWII by the OSS: they wanted something that smelled like excrement to embarrass Japanese officers in China.